# WHERE clause expression references [casted timestamp to date column] which is neither grouped nor aggregated at

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This query should sum up all the records by Error_Type (nested) and by Application(nested) in the Failed_Record_Count column. Total_Record_Count column should sum up all the records from the table(excluding unnested tables). However, an error referencing to **a.timestamp** in the subquery is said to be neither grouped nor aggregated.

I noticed that when removing the "DATE" function from the select list, it successfully executes but doesn't have my expected output. I am expecting that it would be grouped by date and not by timestamp, thus, Im trying to sum up the records by DATE and not by timestamp.

Please help.

```
SELECT
    DATE(timestamp) AS Date,
    status AS Status,
    program_number AS P_No,
    flow AS Flow,
    e.type AS Error_Type,
    e.application AS Application,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            `table` b
        WHERE
            a.status = b.status
            AND a.program_number = b.program_number
            AND a.flow = b.flow
            AND DATE(a.timestamp) = DATE(b.timestamp)
    ) AS Total_Record_Count,
    COUNT(*) AS Failed_Record_Count
FROM
    `table` a,
    UNNEST(evaluation.validation) as ev,
    UNNEST(ev.errors) as e
WHERE
    DATE(timestamp) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
    AND CURRENT_DATE()
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6
ORDER BY 2,3,4,5,6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub query is not considered as an aggregate function in the outer select statement. Hence, you have to add field 7 to group by as shown below:

```
SELECT
    DATE(timestamp) AS Date,
    status AS Status,
    program_number AS P_No,
    flow AS Flow,
    e.type AS Error_Type,
    e.application AS Application,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            `table` b
        WHERE
            a.status = b.status
            AND a.program_number = b.program_number
            AND a.flow = b.flow
            AND DATE(a.timestamp) = DATE(b.timestamp)
    ) AS Total_Record_Count,
    COUNT(*) AS Failed_Record_Count
FROM
    `table` a,
    UNNEST(evaluation.validation) as ev,
    UNNEST(ev.errors) as e
WHERE
    DATE(timestamp) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
    AND CURRENT_DATE()
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
ORDER BY 2,3,4,5,6
```